# DOMContentLoaded is not firing

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension, domcontentloaded

I am trying to create a chrome extension but having problems with DOMContentLoaded as it is not firing.

Note: my code was taken from a different website.
Basically, I have create an `HTML` file with a button:

```
  <head>
<title>GTmetrix Analyzer</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>GTmetrix Analyzer</h1>
    <button id="checkPage">Check this page 
now!</button>
  </body>
```

And this is the **JS file** (popup.js):

```
document.addEventListener
('DOMContentLoaded', 
  function() {
   console.log("f")

  var checkPageButton = 
  document.getElementById('checkPage');


 checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', 
    function() {

  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, 
  function(tab) {
    d = document;

  var f = d.createElement('form');
  f.action = 'http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm';
  f.method = 'post';
  var i = d.createElement('input');
  i.type = 'hidden';
  i.name = 'url';
  i.value = tab.url;
  f.appendChild(i);
  d.body.appendChild(f);
  f.submit();

   });

  }, false);
}, false);
```

I added the console.log event in order to check if the event is executed, so this is how I verified that it isn't working.
I also added  `run_at": "document_start`
but then I got

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

For the "click" event, so I guess that the event was triggered before the button was created.

Help, please!

Comment: The popup is a separate page with its own URL and devtools. To view its console, right-click the popup, then click "Inspect". Also, submitting a form will replace your popup page with the server response page, which is probably not what you want, so consider using XHR/fetch instead.

Comment: Thanks  wOxxOm, it is indeed executed now (verified by adding some console.log events and checking the popup.html console like you suggested). However, the code itself is not working so I am not sure what's wrong (the form). I do want it to replace the popup page.

Comment: I used console.log(f) to see the form submission and I can see it. However, the pop up html file is not being replaced with the request and response. I do want it to be replaced/open a new tab with the results.

Comment: To open the response in a new tab set `f.target = '_blank'`